# Strange behavior during array allocation in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, windows, numpy, memory-management

Can someone explain why I obtain such strange and different times during array allocation, it turns out that it **25x** times faster to allocate slightly bigger array and slice it, than to allocate the array of needed size:

```
%timeit arr = np.zeros((360, 360))
207 µs ± 4.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
arr = np.zeros((362, 362))
arr = arr[:360]
8.4 µs ± 651 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Is there something general behind that or it is some Windows related issue? While this situation is specific near **`(360, 360) size`** on my computer, I do not know if it can arise at other places.

**EDIT:** While this question is marked as a duplicate, the answer to that question does not not fully explain the problem:

```
%timeit -n10 -r10 arr = np.zeros((361, 361))
243 µs ± 56.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit -n10 -r10 arr = np.zeros((362, 362))
6.82 µs ± 539 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

With **`zeros`** there is **25-35x** regression, but with **`empty`** the story is in opposite direction with **2-5x**:

```
%timeit -n10 -r10 arr = np.empty((361, 361))
2.49 µs ± 1.02 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit -n10 -r10 arr = np.empty((362, 362))
11.9 µs ± 1.58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10 loops each)
```

*Windows 7

Python 3.6.3

numpy 1.13.3*

Comment: I need to allocate a lot of arrays with the size `(360,360)` during my calculations, so this accumulated overhead beats me very hard.

Comment: Stupid question, but are the numbers consistent? Can you reproduce this 25x every time? Or maybe the first needed some time to evict pages from RAM to allocate the required space?

Comment: @sascha the results are the same.

Comment: What happens if you do the `362` case first?

Comment: @MattClark yes they are consistent, if we consider not this naked version, this difference yields me *25%* overhead.

Comment: @hpaulj the results are the same, but if I run `%timeit -n1 -r1` in the loop the usual difference is about `10x`.

Comment: The post marked as a duplicate seems to explain this behavior. Once you cross a threshold it no longer actually allocates the memory.

Comment: When I try to reproduce your example in the interpreter I get a slightly longer time for your second case. Same on [TIO](https://tio.run/##jY1LCsMwDET3PoXJygIT8oEuWnyS0oUDJjXEtpDVRXp5VyU5QAQjIWl4gzu/S55biwkLsc6fhLv2VWdU54ljCpGVQoqZzbH1FDB4Np0n0k7M/TdQqcbMt8GKADr7Zy2B3DhIWb1uZfFbdec0AHAVOQlyAngcH@nPu2S8rkS09gM)